# Hiding a form-group with Flask Jinja2 and WTForms

Tags: jquery, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to show or hide a form field based on the state of a checkbox in another part of the form. I thought that I could do this with jQuery .show() or .hide() with relative ease, but I'm not having much luck so far. Any thoughts?

The form class:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    checked = BooleanField('Check this box:')
    date = DateField('Date:', format='%Y-%m-%d', id="dates")
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

The template:

```
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block content %}

{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.checked) }}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.date) }}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.submit) }}

{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checked").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#dates').show();
    } else {
      $('#dates').hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are using [Flask-Bootstrap](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/).

First, make sure you include `{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}` in your template. Without that line, you'll lose out on everything Flask-Bootstrap includes in the template, such as jQuery.

Second, you are overriding the `scripts` block. This is where Flask-Bootstrap includes jQuery. In order to put your own stuff there without losing the base version, you need to use [Jinja's `super` function](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#super-blocks). It will include the parent template's `scripts` block along with your own.

After making these changes your template should look something like

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block content %}
    <form>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.checked) }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.date) }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.submit) }}
    </form>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $("#checked").change(function() {
                if (this.checked) {
                    $('#dates').show();
                } else {
                    $('#dates').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}` is included in my layout. I included jquery in the static dir before I added bootstrap, so I know that jquery is loading. `console.log()`s are also telling me that the script is executing. It's just not toggling the dates form group.

Comment: Placing jQuery in your `static` folder doesn't add it to the page. Without including it in the template, it won't be included. The toggle works using your form and my modified version of the template. Since you've mentioned a couple of things that aren't in your example, what does your actual template look like?

Comment: You were right. Looks like it was an issue of using `{{ super() }}`. I was confused because I hadn't been getting jQuery is undefined errors.

Comment: I know this is a super old question, but I'm using this approach with a BooleanField object, and while it can hide the checkbox part, it seems to leave the label for some reason.

Comment: @Brendan a lot has probably changed in the almost 6 and a half years since this answer was written. You’re better off asking a new question. You can always reference this one from it. I haven’t used Flask-WTF in several years, but my guess would be to try passing `label=“”`.